# How to match the matched case as well as another below cases?

Tags: scala, switch-statement, match, break

I know that I **can not** use `break` in the **Scala** `match` statement.

Is there a why to match the matched case as well as some below cases?

For example in **Java** I can do the following :

```
int i=3;
switch(i) {
    case 1:
        a();
        break;
    case 2:
        b();
    case 3:
        c();
    case 4:
        d();
        break;
    default: z();
}
```

How I can do the same thing on the **Scala**?

Comment: You will need to repeat the code. The lack of automatic `break` in Java and other languages is a significant source of errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done, but you have to define your own `switch` method.

```
// switch statement with dropthrough logic
def switch[T](i: T)(actions: (T, () => Unit)*)(default: => Unit) = {
  val acts = actions.dropWhile(_._1 != i).map{_._2}
  if (acts.isEmpty) default
  else acts.foreach{_()}
}
```

This works, but it has a slightly unorthodox syntax. And because it requires a `return`, instead of `break`, there should be no code that follows this `switch`.

```
def someMethod(i:Int): Unit =
  switch(i)(
    1 -> {() => println("do 1"); return}, // return instead of break
    2 -> {() => println("do 2")},
    3 -> {() => println("do 3")},
    4 -> {() => println("do 4")}  // no comma after final case
  )(default = println("do default"))
```

All in all, likely to be more hassle than it's worth.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to write the code twice (or more). In Scala it is not possible to fall through from one `case` to the next. Even in languages where it is possible, it is generally not a good idea; it can be a source of hard-to-find bugs (although there are situations where it can be used effectively).

In Scala the code would look like this:

```
val i = 3
i match {
  case 1 => a()
  case 2 => {
    b()
    c()
    d()
  }
  case 3 => {
    c()
    d()
  }
  case 4 => d()
  case _ => z()
```

Comment: thanks, that a great solution, do you think that there is another way without duplicate code

Comment: @AhmadAl-Kurdi: That depends on your actual use case. Maybe a new method with an appropriate name that makes the calls (`e()`). If the methods is always used in succession, you could add for example `c()` to the start of `d()`. In my opinion, if there are just a couple of method calls like this, leave it as it is. In this way the flow of the program is easy to follow.

Answer (score 0):

You can't translate your Java code directly to Scala without code duplication as you can't execute several alternatives in match statement in a single pass.
What you can do however to avoid code duplication in alternatives is to process the same match statement multiple times,

for example

```
@tailrec
def switch(x : Int): Unit =
     x match {
       case 1 => a()
       case 2 => b(); switch(3)
       case 3 => c(); switch(4)
       case 4 => c()
       case _ => z()
     }

switch(3)
```

Comment: Because switch here is not a special Scala construct (like in Java) but a function (or method) which wraps match statement. As it is a function it obviously should be called somewhere. switch call in the last line is called outside the function (i.e. it is initial call of that function) unlike other switch class which are inside.